# WopiDiscovery endpoint throws error : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient, ms-wopi

Does anyone encoutered an  [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnUVM.png) like this. It works before a month ago, when I tried again to run the application is not working anymore.

Wopi Discovery endpoint: https://ffc-onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery

Github: https://github.com/apulliam/WOPIFramework

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Are you sure this appsettings gives correct value?